# Implementing Yelp business photos into iPhone app like Apple Maps

Tags: ios6, foursquare, photos, yelp

I'm curious how one might mimic Apple Map's iOS6 approach to showing Yelp photos. For example, when a user searches and clicks on a business, Maps shows a rotating slideshow of photos from Yelp's collection of pictures for that venue. The photos are shown with fade in/fade out transitions.

Does anyone know how to implement this? Also, might the same approach/functionality be offered using the foursquare API?

Answer (score 0):

The Yelp API won't let you (only the first image is available), but if you where to use their API you could get the business yelp url and scrape the pictures from the actual page, **BUT** that would involve a lot of maintenance and I don't know it that would interfere with their terms (legal?)